# ReactJS - Multiple Popup Drawers in same page not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am currently working on a sales project page using ReactJS. I have two forms, a PQ (purchase quotation) create form, and a requirement create form. I am using Ant Design for my popup drawer (it slides out from the side so that I can fill in the form on that popup instead of going to a new page). However, when I added 2 drawers to the same page, the popup drawer no longer works. I added an argument to the method 'showDrawer' which takes in the name of the drawer that I want to pop up whenever I click on the 'create PQ' or 'create requirement button', However, the button no longer works, and the drawer is permanently on the screen right now, with no functionality to remove it from the screen. I do not know what to do anymore, hopefully I can get some help or guidance from you guys here. My code is shown below.

```
state = {
     visible: {
        requirementCreate: false,
        PQCreate: false,
        SQCreate: false
    }
}
```

these are the methods for opening and closing the drawers

```
showDrawer = (obj) => {
    var visibility = { ...this.state.visible }
    console.log(this.state.visible);
    console.log(visibility);
    visibility[obj] = true;
    console.log(visibility);
    this.setState({ visibility });
}

onClose = (obj) => {
    var visibility = { ...this.state.visible }
    console.log(visibility);
    visibility[obj] = false;
    console.log(visibility);
    this.setState({ visibility });
}
```

this is the drawer for the requirement create form

```
<Button type="primary" className='float-right' onClick={() => this.showDrawer('requirementCreate')}>
     <PlusOutlined /> Add Requirement
</Button>
<Drawer
   title="Create a new requirement"
   width={720}
   onClose={() => this.onClose('requirementCreate')}
   visible={this.state.visible}
   bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
   >
       <RequirementCreate hideRequiredMark id={this.props.match.params.id} onSubmit={() => 
        this.onClose('requirementCreate')} />
</Drawer>
```

this is the drawer for the PQ create form

```
<Button type="primary" className='float-right' onClick={() => this.showDrawer('PQCreate')}>
    <PlusOutlined /> Add PQ
</Button>
<Drawer
    title="Create a new purchase quotation"
    width={720}
    onClose={() => this.onClose('PQCreate')}
    visible={this.state.visible}
    bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
    >
        <QuotationCreate hideRequiredMark id={this.props.match.params.id} quotation='pq' onSubmit= 
        {() => this.onClose('PQCreate')} />
</Drawer>
```

i took this Drawer component from Ant Design, the link is here https://ant.design/components/drawer/

All help is appreciated, really hope that this can be solved! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of All, the state variable `visible` you have used must be a key-value pair in order to make the Drawer work. It should not be an object. And, use separate visible data for each drawer component. 
The state should be quite like this.

```
state = {
     reqCreateVisible: false,
     pqCreateVisible : false,
     requirementCreate: false,
     PQCreate: false,
     SQCreate: false
    }
}
```

Drawers should be configured as below.

**Requirement Create Drawer**

```
<Drawer
   title="Create a new requirement"
   width={720}
   onClose={() => this.onClose('requirementCreate')}
   visible={this.state.reqCreateVisible}
   bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
   >
   <RequirementCreate hideRequiredMark id={this.props.match.params.id} onSubmit={() => 
    this.onClose('requirementCreate')} />
</Drawer>
```

**PQ Create Drawer**

```
<Drawer
    title="Create a new purchase quotation"
    width={720}
    onClose={() => this.onClose('PQCreate')}
    visible={this.state.pqCreateVisible}
    bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
    >
    <QuotationCreate hideRequiredMark id={this.props.match.params.id} 
        quotation='pq' onSubmit= {() => this.onClose('PQCreate')} />
</Drawer>
```

And you're `showDrawer` has to be configured as well. You are using two same components, if you are changing only single `visible` data then both the drawers would clash and cause you an issue.

```
showDrawer = (obj) => {
    if(obj === "requirementCreate")
      this.setState({ reqCreateVisible: true });
    else if(obj === "PQCreate")
      this.setState({ pqCreateVisible: true});
}
```

Similarly the same has to be applied for `closeDrawer` method too.

```
onClose = (obj) => {
    if(obj === "requirementCreate")
      this.setState({ reqCreateVisible: false });
    else if(obj === "PQCreate")
      this.setState({ pqCreateVisible: false});
}
```

Summary,
 Usage of separate visible data on components will solve your issue. There has to be proper usage of updating the state data. Please do read the documentation thoroughly before proceeding to design your application. Hope it helps!!.. **Happy Coding!!**